# SSH and SCP piggyback ubuntu machine for a new user

Tags: ssh, users, non-root-user, account-restrictions

I want to use an existing Ubuntu machine (with a public IP) to allow a user to SSH into it and then use it to SSH/RemoteDesktop/FTP into another linux machine (with a private IP but within the 1st machine's network).

I would create a new user account for this purpose, but I want to:

1. Restrict sudo access to this user
2. Not be able to go into other users ***/home/otheruser*** directory

How to do it?

Comment: Creating vpn would be a much better solution to reach lan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to setup is usually called a jumpbox.

Users are not added to the wheel group automatically, so you only need to `useradd` the new user, and you are good to go